# bbPress - Post count increases after every edit

Tags: bbpress

I’ve installed bbPress 2.4 recently and I’ve noticed that each time I edit a post, my post count increases. Is there a way to stop that from happening? Thanks.

> [image: screenshot]

P.S. Is it normal for this to happen or is there something wrong on my end?

Comment: Post count _where_ exactly?

Comment: In the forums I've installed for my WordPress site, using the bbPress plugin. http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ab1qnuec1

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to bbPress 2.4, bbPress 2.x at this stage does not include this functionality out of the box. I expect you are using an additional plugin to add the 'Post count: 1' functionality to bbPress and your issues relate to that plugin.